# Slider bad shifting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this slider that i'm using, whenever i click the next or previous buttons it shifts in a way covering some elements of my website. I believe the problem in the #mask and i tried to change a bit in it but without any difference, any idea on if it's causing the problem or something else? and any solution?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Gallery</title>
        <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
       body {
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:grey;

}
#prev {
    left: 40px;
}
#next {
    right: 40px;
}
#mask {
    width: 50000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.item {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}
.content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 17%;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}
.content a {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 170px;
}
.selected {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}



        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
        <h1><p id="prev">&lt;</p></h1>
        <h1><p id="next">&gt;</p></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="mask">
        <div id="item1" class="item"> <a name="item1"></a>

            <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="slot1" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item">
            <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="slot2" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item">
            <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="slot2" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>






<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newItem = 0;
    var itemCount = $('.item').length;

    function shift(direction) {
        var $mask = $('#mask'),
            $items = $('.item'),
            currentItem = $mask.data('currentItem');

        if (currentItem === undefined) {
            currentItem = 0;
        }

        $mask.data('currentItem', newItem).animate({
            marginLeft: -newItem * $items.eq(0).width()
        });
    }

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if (newItem === 0) {
            newItem = itemCount - 1;
        } else {
            newItem--;
        }
        return shift();
    });
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (newItem === itemCount - 1) {
            newItem = 0;
        } else {
            newItem++;
        }
        return shift();
    });

    function resizePanel() {
        width = $(window).width();
        height = $(window).height();

        $('#wrapper, .item').css({
            width: width,
            height: height
        });
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });
    resizePanel();
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ew98y5fv/

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not contain any other elements, so cant say what the problem is. Please could you add another element to your fiddle which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar see the way the dividers are shifting to ultimate left/right before disappearing. So they are passing over other elements in the page

Comment: I think you asked a question before regarding some navigation units. So the answer here would be similar. I'll try and add a bit of code to demonstrate. You need to separate the slider logic from the rest of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified you html:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slider-container">
        <div id="nav">
            <p id="prev">&lt;</p>
            <p id="next">&gt;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-view-area">
            <div id="mask">
                <div id="item1" class="item"> <a name="item1"></a>

                    <div class="content">
                        <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="slot1" />
                        <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="item2" class="item">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="slot2" />
                        <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="item3" class="item">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="slot2" />
                        <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                        <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#slider-container {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slider-view-area {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:grey;

}
#prev {
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#next {
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#mask {
    width: 50000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.item {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}
.content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 17%;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}
.content a {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 170px;
}
.selected {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

I removed h1 tags around your navigation elements because you should not use header tags for display changes like making the icons look bigger. For that you should use css. h1 tags will be semantically incorrect in this case, because a navigation element is not a primary header.

I have just gone for a quick fix. But its the direction you should take if you want to make the slider into an independent component in your page.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ew98y5fv/3/

Comment: thank you for your help. But one question, if i re-size the result tab in the JSfiddle, the other dividers beside the current appear.Why?

Comment: When resized you are setting window width to wrapper and item. I do not know the purpose of this, since the width is anyway 100%. But this may have something to do with the behaviour.

Comment: should i remove this funtion?

Comment: Here is a modification taking into account the padding and space around it:  https://jsfiddle.net/ew98y5fv/4/ I think it may be required, or a lot of css changes is required to make your content fit. Since inside each viewing section, there seems to be a lot of items and that is likely to get cropped in tiny viewing areas.

Comment: just one final question, what did you manipulate to make the div disappear before the buttons?

Comment: I added a container div with class 'slider-view-area' with overflow hidden around your masked content. and then added another container div around your nav and your slider container. This makes your slider a unit with a viewport as wide as the '.slider-view-area'. The outer container is for adding navigation elements and positioning them within it. I gave the outer container some padding, for the nav elements.

Comment: seriously man you don't know what you did for me, i've been working around this slider for a couple of days now. I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to hear that! Good luck with the slider!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81125/discussion-between-randy-and-arathi-sreekumar).

Comment: I have joined the chat